# Blender does not display texts

Tags: 22.04, suspend, interface, 23.04, blender

I am currently using Ubuntu 23.04 and this problem occurred when I had 22.04. When I had Ubuntu 22.04, when my system was suspended, all the images, shapes, and texts turned into noisy images, so I had to reset my laptop. Once when Blender was open, I accidentally suspended the laptop and when I turned it on, I saw that my Blender screen looked like this.

[image]

I tried many times to fix this problem and I downloaded Blender from different versions and from different sites, but this problem was not solved. When I upgraded my Ubuntu version to 23.04, the problem of suspending the laptop was solved, but when I installed Blender again, I saw that it is still the same.